# Conexión de base de datos en python con pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, vscode, flask, arquitectura-de-software

Estoy haciendo una función para obtener la conexión a una base de datos utilizando la librería pymssql

```
from decouple import config
import pymssql


def get_conection():
    try:
        return pymssql.connect(
            host=config('SERVER'),
            user=config('USER'),
            password=config('PASS'),
            db=config('DB'),
        )
        
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        
get_conection()
```

Pero al momento de correr la funcioón entra el except y me menciona lo siguiente:

```
connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'db'
```

Quisiera saber si así estará bien o si existen algún error dentro del código, la implementare junto a un proyecto en flask pero aun no hago las rutas que correspondan a esta conexión.

Comment: `connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'db'`... Según [la documentacion](http://www.pymssql.org/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.connect) el argumento es  `database` no `db`...

Answer (score 0):

Revisando la documentación de [`pymysql`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) se puede apreciar que las conexiones se realizan actualmente de la siguiente manera, sin embargo deberías verificar que versión de Python y los paquetes que tienes instalado.

1. Lista de paquetes necesarios para realizar la conexión con `Python3`

```bash
> pip3 list   
        
Package Version
------- -------
pip     24.0
PyMySQL 1.1.0
```

2. El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```py
import pymysql 
  
def mysqlconnect(): 
    # Credenciales de conexión a la Base 
    conn = pymysql.connect( 
        host='localhost', 
        user='dbeaver',  
        password = "dbeaver", 
        db='db_testing', 
        ) 
      
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")  # realizo una consulta para verificar que bases de datos tengo disponibles 
    output = cur.fetchall() 
    print(output) 
      
    # Para cerrar la conexión
    conn.close() 
  
# llamamos la función
if __name__ == "__main__" : 
    mysqlconnect()
```

3. Ejecutamos y obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

```
> python3 test.py 
    
(('db_testing',), ('information_schema',), ('mysql',), ('performance_schema',), ('sys',))
```